# Susy 2 Alpha 4 Grid Layout

Tags: css, grid, sass, susy-compass

I have my grid defined as:

```
$twelve-grid: 8 1/2 after static float
```

and then my divs set up as follows:

```
+use-grid($twelve-grid)
  .fact-circle-container
    +clearfix
    +background-grid

    li
      +span(2)
      +nth-omega(4)
```

But the outcome is like this:

[image]

Any thoughts? Really confusing me

Answer (score 0):

You set it up as a static grid, but you never established a container, so you're getting static output on the columns, but they're in a fluid context. You can ditch both `clearfix` and `background-grid`, and replace them with `container` (which includes both of those, as well as a width).

I'm not sue how static is even working, since it should require a `$column-width` setting...

Comment: (or you can ditch the static setting, and it will all work fluidly, of course)

Comment: Thanks for that. Replaced static with fluid and it's working perfectly! Thanks. Is Susy 2 being released this year?

Comment: I hope so. We'll be ready as soon as the new versions of Sass & Compass land. I've heard that should be very soon, but it's hard to make promises in the world of open-source software.